# Why does browser send a preflight request to the same origin?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

My site performs AJAX request to a relative URL, i.e. to a resource with the same origin. Why do browsers (both IE 11 and Chrome) send a preflight (OPTIONS) request? What could be the reason? If I perform this request from the browser console, only the POST request is sent.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/some/path/Export/",
    data: JSON.stringify({ data: [] }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(t) {
        window.location.href = "/some/path/Download?file=" + t
    },
    error: function(t, e, r) {
        console.log(t, e, r)
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
})
```

Comment: "Setting withCredentials has no effect on same-site requests" ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)) so you can remove it.

Comment: Most likely you have some redirect or base url logic which prevents it from being a same origin request. There's no way to tell from the code supplied though.